# One of my pages keeps showing file not found

Tags: http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages, file-not-found

I used react to develop my website and deployed it on github pages, but the problem is, the home page works, but other pages cannot be found. It loads shows the page and then suddenly goes off and says “404, file can not be found” after few seconds.

I don’t understand why, I have tried various methods to fix it. Kindly help.

My repository is:
https://github.com/Bunmi2020/valor-motion-pictures

The website is https://valormotionpictures.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.